# Applescript for macports repository maintenance

Tags: applescript, macports, automator

Cannot create a useful script for scheduling the macports update and upgrade weekly e.g..

I tried a tiny script here:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    do shell script "sudo /opt/local/bin/port selfupdate && sudo /opt/local/bin/port upgrade outdated && sudo /opt/local/bin/port clean --all installed" user name "<username>" password "<password>" with administrator privileges

    return input
end run
```

And put this into Automator

Then as it running, the window will be frozen and if anything returns during the run, it shows as an exception message.

Can you write a useful script to get things done?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off looking into the cron utility, that nowadays must be explicitly enabled. For all what I know, you can also get hold of a utility named Cronnix, to set it up. Your other alternative is to use Launchctl, here there is a friendly user interface named Lingon, that you can buy from the appstore.

There will always be an error log from updating MacPorts, that you should really read. The other thing is that when some packages gets deprecated, or some conflict occurs, then the update command really will require you to interact, by moving stuff aside, so the approach of using something to update Macports isn't as favourable as it may seem.

How about creating a recurring calendar event reminding you to do it? :)

If you are really tenacious about getting this to work, then you'll have to use the do shell script with administrator privileges, and if you don't like the dialog with password, and username, then you can hardcode those into your automator action. You'll then have to let go of sudo, since the ´with administrator privileges` does that for you.

```
        do shell script "your shell script without sudo" user name "hardcodedusername" password "hardcodedpassword" with administrator privileges
```

Comment: Okay, I just want to learn the tech way, by scripting the event. So the point is `return input` will let the program return the screen output as an exception and during the run the window is freezing. Can this be fixed by modifying my Applescript?

Comment: I have modified my answer above slightly, added the necessary do shell script with administrator privileges. What the AppleScript Action returns is what you define to be in the input variable at the time it returns, it is never the screen, nor can it be, but you could return the path to a screen shot you have captured, by using the screencapture commandline utility.

Comment: The "tech way" is to use launchd (or the old-timey cron) to run your shell script directly. Anything more is just needless baggage.